# What do I need to whitelist on my firewall for Office 365 email accounts using Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-365

This one particular customer of mine has their email accounts at Microsoft Office 365. They are all using Outlook 2013 on their workstations to connect to these accounts. Unfortunately that have a SonicWall TZ300 firewall that implements content filtering and as a result Outlook on their workstations can't connect to their email accounts. Does anyone know what sites I have to allow through the content filtering so Outlook can connect to their email accounts?

Answer (score 0):

We could find the latest Office 365 URLs and IP address ranges in this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide), and it also supplies all required and optional destinations in one JSON formatted list and some suggestions about how to access the data, please kindly check it and configure the endpoints as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I came across that link early on and scratched my head. 2 million entries? It actually turned out to be just two:

*.office365.com
*.outlook.com

with just those two everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.
I think the detailed URL address may be designed to help us meet specific requirement of fuction on different service area when we need.